# Any way to monitor a Java application's Function Flow?

Tags: java, performance, monitoring, execution

At my new assignment, I need to understand a mid level Java application. To understand the flow faster, I had this idea that if I could see at runtime functions are being called, which function finally responded, then I could really get the whole map in my mind.

I've worked with tools like AppDynamics which tells the latency/DB calls etc. But what I am looking after is something which will tell me the flow at Runtime. 
Like, 
`Controller.getStudent() -> Service.getStudent() -> Repository.getStudent() -> ....`

I am wondering if there are any tools/techniques as such. Like recording a stacktrace in debug mode. I can imagine a tool doing `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`. Does anybody have some idea regarding how can do this?  (I'm using Springboot and Jboss)

Edit: I'm not really looking after logging, debugging etc. I feel there could be something which could tell what functions are being executed. And determine if there are any limitations.

Comment: add logging in your methods, and follow the logs

Comment: with Spring-boot, you can add an aspect to auto-add trace on method being called

Answer (score 2):

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class FunctionTraceAspect {
    @Before("execution(* some.package.*.*.*(..))")
    public void appendUserContext(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("TRACE: " + joinPoint.getSignature());
   }
}
```